# Set a default bean to autowire if byName fails

Tags: java, spring

I have numerous IO classes that all require PKI info (key & truststore) be autowired into them so they can establish connections.  Currently we use the same PKI info in all places, but we may eventually want different PKI for different interfaces.

For this reason I would like to be able to @autowire byName in each interface, allowing a unique name for each PKI which I could later decide to inject via xml if I want unique PKIs, but also have spring default to autowireing my single 'main' PKI information if the autowire name can't be found (because I haven't yet had the need to define a unique PKI bean instead of defaults for that instance).

I believe this works perfectly fine if I only have only one Keystore bean, but I'm not sure what happens if I have two.

Say I have three places where I autowire my keystore, with name foo, bar, and baz.  I originally register one keystore bean, I think all thee get this global bean regardless of the byName because only one type exists.

I then add a keystore bean named foo, which should be autowired to the keystore with byName=foo set.  However, how do I make sure that both the bar and baz keystores, which do not yet have a bean of the appropriate name defined, still know to fall back to loading my 'default' keystore?

Comment: Hey, please add some code examples. From my perspective in your `@Autowire` you can add `@Qualifier` but remember to register your KeystoreImpl2 with correct name using `@Bean("keystore2")` notation to your spring context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly it should be sth like this.

```
public interface Keystore{}

@Component("keystoreImplFirst")
public class KeystoreImplFirst implements Keystore{}

@Component("keystoreImplSecond")
public class KeystoreImplSecond implements Keystore{}
```

Then the usage:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("keystoreImplFirst")
Keystore keystore;
```

You can use `@Resource` annotation too but keep in mind that name will be resolved according to your variable name. More explanation and examples you can find there [LINK](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/)

```
@Resource
Keystore keystoreImplFirst
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for.  I know this can be done if I define each component ahead of time.  My question is more about how to do this so that there is a default keystore implementation that is loaded for keystoreImplSecond when it sees I haven't yet defined a bean with that name (the point being to leave a quick way to plug in keystores by simply defining a bean of the appropriate name if we want to stop using a generic keystore for one of the examples)

Comment: Ok, so I think in this situation you need to manipulate a little bit around application context or bean factory where all beans are registered and do appropriate logic in component that is utilizing your keystore abstraction.